# Show that the limit of an integral goes to 0

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that 
$$
\lim \limits_{k \rightarrow \infty } \int \limits_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(kx)dx = 0 \textit{ and } \lim \limits_{k \rightarrow \infty } \int \limits_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(kx)dx = 0
$$
I am assuming that $f \in L^2(-\pi, \pi)$ and that the sequence 
$$
\lbrace \phi_k\rbrace_{k=1}^\infty= \lbrace \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}, \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}},..., \frac{\cos(kx)}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \frac{\sin(kx)}{\sqrt{\pi}},... \rbrace 
$$
is orthonormal and in $L^2(-\pi, \pi)$. I have started the problem by using the Bessel inequality, which says that $\sum \limits _ {k=1}^\infty h_k^2 \leq \parallel f \parallel_2^2 $ where $h_k = \langle f, \phi_k \rangle$. I know that all elements of the sequence are orthogonal so $\langle f_k, f_l \rangle= 0$ where $k,l \in R$ and $k \neq l$. I also now that the sequence is orthonormal so $\parallel f \parallel_2 = 1$.

I can rewrite the Bessel inequality as follows
$$
\sum \limits _ {k=1}^\infty h_k^2 \leq \parallel f \parallel_2^2 \Rightarrow \sum \limits _ {k=1}^\infty \langle f, \phi_k \rangle^2 \leq 1
$$
This can be simplified further to 
$$
\sum \limits _ {k=1}^\infty \int \limits_{-\pi}^\pi (f \phi_k ) \int \limits_{-\pi}^\pi (f \phi_k )\leq 1 \Rightarrow \sum \limits _ {k=1}^\infty \int \limits_{-\pi}^\pi (f \phi_k )^2 \leq 1
$$
From here I am stuck. Was my methodology correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For notation, I'll denote the orthonormal sequence by $\{e_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ where $e_k = \frac{e^{ik}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.  This is clearly an orthonormal sequence.  By Besell's inequality, we have that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (f,e_k)^2 \le ||f||_2^2$.  Since $f \in L^2$, $||f||_2 < \infty$, and so Bessell's inequality tells us in particular that this sum converges.  Hence $\lim_{k\to \infty} (f,e_k)^2 = 0$, from which we may conclude that $(f,e_k) \to 0$.  Use this together with the definition of $(f,e_k)$ to conclude that the integrals go to $0$.

Comment: I understand what you are saying for the most part, but how can you say that the $\lim (f,e_k) = 0$ if the sum converges. Would we need to know what the sum converges to before we can say what the limit converges to?

Comment: The only other theorem I have says that if the sequence converges then $\lim \limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \parallel f_k - f\parallel = 0$. Is that what you are using?

Comment: If $\{c_n\}$ is a sequence of complex numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = 0$.

Comment: I don't think the sequence I provided had any complex values, so that theorem wouldn't hold, would it?

Comment: $(f,e_k)$ is just some number.  It's obtained by integrating f against e^-ikx.